# running QWidget in JNI library without QMainWindow

Tags: java, c++, qt, java-native-interface, printf

linux : I have a simple **c++** jni test library created with qtcreator, which works

now I need to put the real jni library code which was tested being part of a regular qt app and some java into the final jni library

I also created a very simple console output widget based upon the following snippet and it works great in all my qt apps

```
class TConsole : public QPlainTextEdit
{
  Q_OBJECT

  static void Printf (const char *form, ...) ;

  and more
}
```

I tried to call the following dummy main funct (contained in the jni base class) 1st in the jni library constructor with some dummy **argc** and **argv**

```
int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
  QApplication a (argc, argv) ;

  TConsole console ;
  console.show () ;

  a.exec () ;
}
```

but I get the following err :
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

what's the secret to pop up a widget like described within a jni library
I really need the debug output to this console output widget since i don't know of another easy way to print something from within the jni **c++** code while it's being executed from the outer java app
also i would prefer this console widget over regular `printf()` statements since my jni code contains lots of custom print macros to this window

any help is highest appreciated

Comment: actually the real jni target code was also part of a regular qt app and tested as such ... no java was involved during these tests as falsely stated ... only the simple jni test code was tested with a java test app to make sure the jni implementation works

Answer (score 0):

getting any msg out through the c++ environment like printf would require opening a console or my own "class TConsole : public QPlainTextEdit", all didn't work.

what i have not seen initially is the availability to provide a path to java via a jni function returning a java byte array carrying the msg

now i went this route and it works

in the java jni interface def file i created

```
public native final byte [] Msg () ;
```

and in the c++ counterpart

```
jbyteArray Java_com_efiLabs_TUniTalkLib_Msg (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
  TJniLib *inst = getHandle <TJniLib> (env, obj) ;

  int len = ::MsgPrn.length () ;
  jbyteArray ba = env->NewByteArray (len) ;
  env->SetByteArrayRegion  (ba,  0,  len,
                reinterpret_cast <jbyte *> (inst->Msg ())) ;
  return ba ;
}
```

and the c++ messaging code is as follows in JniLib.h

```
uchar   *Msg (void) ;
```

and in the JniLib.cpp

```
QString MsgPrn ;

uchar *TJniLib::Msg (void)
{
  QString s = ::MsgPrn ;
  if (::MsgPrn.length ()) MsgPrn.clear () ;
  return (uchar *) s.toStdString ().c_str () ;
}
```

i can now poll periodically in java for "Msg ()" returning the debug msg if the array length > 0

i'll probably put a sw fifo into the c++ code to have less impact on the submitting the message